# How to add a link to routes in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am very new to CodeIgniter. I want to edit a link. It was first like this in original

`$route['products'] = 'front/products';`

but I need a url to be here. like. So that when a user clicks on Products on Navigation, it should take to the external site url like `example.com`

`$route['products'] = 'https://example.com/';`

Comment: there is no such thing as a route with a link (anchor), you provide that right in the anchor. Maybe you mix up [CI Routing](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html) with creating an [anchor](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/url_helper.html?highlight=anchor#anchor).

Answer (score 0):

Routes are not the same as navigation links.
It sounds like you want to edit the navigation links to point to an external domain / site.

Routes control internal site URLs and which controller services them.
E.g. you may want to /news/ to use a 'blog' controller as they're similar content types.

I'd suggest looking through your views folder and try to ascertain which code is generating the navigation, then update from there in the HTML for the navigation list.